# What’s the difference between sx and σx in the statistics calculations on a TI-Nspire?

Tags: standard-deviation, ti-nspire

I know that sx is the standard deviation of a sample and σx is the standard deviation of a population. My question is, does the TI-Nspire think that the data I entered is a sample or the population? If it think’s (A) my data is a sample, how is σx calculated? If it thinks (B) my data is the population, how is it taking a “sample”?

I think (A) makes sense and the calculator is somehow estimating a population standard deviation (σx) through some normal distribution approximation.

Possibly ...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation

However, I can’t find any reference to confirm this and I want to be sure.

Note: Actually using the TI-Nspire CX CAS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After cross-checking in Excel and reading [Bessel’s correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) and [Unbiased estimation of standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) on Wikipedia …

`σx` gives the “regular” standard deviation and `sx` applies Bessel’s correction. In other words, `σx` is the exact standard deviation of the data given (with `n` in the denominator), and `sx` is an unbiased estimation of the standard deviation of a larger population assuming that the data given is only a sample of that population (i.e. with `n-1` in the denominator).